# "Sticky rows" for jquery tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using jquery tablesorter in my project, and now i need some functionality i could not find in that plugin or any of it subplugins. Maybe i'm using a wrong term, but i need something like "sticky rows".
Before, i had pretty standart tables, like

```
<table> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
<th>Head1</th> 
<th>Head2</th> 
<th>Head3</th> 
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody> 
<tr>
<td>cell1.1</td>
<td>cell1.2</td>
<td>cell1.3</td>
</tr>
...
</tbody> 
</table>
```

and tablesorter worked well with it.

Now, i need something like:

```
<table> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
<th>Head1</th> 
<th>Head2</th> 
<th>Head3</th> 
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody> 
<tr>
<td>cell1.1</td>
<td>cell1.2</td>
<td>cell1.3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>cell1.4</td>
<td collspan="2">cell1.5</td>
</tr>
...
</tbody> 
</table>
```

and to keep old sorting working.

That meens, i need tablesorter to ignore row with cell1.4 and cell1.5 (and so on with the next even rows), sort the not-ignored rows in table, and than append the appropriate ignored before row to appropriate not-ignored row (so that row with cell 1.4 and 1.5 allways follow the row with cell1.1). In other worlds, i want row with cells 1.4 and 1.5 to stick to the previous row and so on. For this, i need to find the way to mark the row for the required functionality (either with tablesorter parameters or with  attributes).

I didn't find appropriate functionality in tablesorter docs. How this can be achieved?

Comment: What is the property that makes a row "sticky"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking about child rows ([demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-child-rows.html)). To make this work in tablesorter, just add the class name "tablesorter-childRow" to any row that will be attached to the row above it.

```
<tr>
    <td>cell1.1</td>
    <td>cell1.2</td>
    <td>cell1.3</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
    <td>cell1.4</td>
    <td collspan="2">cell1.5</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You should include the tablesorter declaration in the answer. took me a bit to figure out that you need to declare the child row class in the tablesorter declaration

Comment: @chiliNUT Sorry, the class name shown is the default setting, to change the class name modify the [`cssChildRow` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#csschildrow).

Comment: I read that in the documentation, but I don't think there is any default setting, or at least it wasn't working for me. I tried `"tablesorter-childRow"` and `"expand-child"` and nothing worked for me until I specified the class in the tablesorter declaration